# Get documents thumbnail using pnp-js-core or rest api

Tags: document-library, jsom, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx, pnp-js-core

How can I get documents thumbnail using pnp-js-core or rest api.

I need to render a document card with its thumbnail.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say thumbnail, do you mean the document type icon or something else?

Answer (score 0):

This parameter expects a value equal to the URL of the document/file for which you want to generate a thumbnail. To generate a preview, the URL should look like this:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test_layouts/15/getpreview.ashx?path=https%3A%2F%2Ftenant.sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2Ftest%2FTestWork.mp4
```